# Matlab, vision.peopledetector with Motion-Based Multiple Object Tracking?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, detection, matlab-cvst

I have been researching methods to detect people only in the video from a security camera. I want to use `vision.peopledetector` with `vision.BlobAnalysis` and `vision.ForegroundDetector`. But it doesn't work.

It should be like Motion-Based Multiple Object Tracking example, but only for detecting humans. Cant seem to get it work.

What I have done so far without using `vision.BlobAnalysis` and `vision.ForegroundDetector. It is not accurate at all and cant count

```
video = VideoReader('atrium.mp4');
peopleDetector = vision.PeopleDetector;
videoPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer;

while hasFrame(video)
   img = readFrame(video);
   [bboxes,scores] = step(peopleDetector,img);
   D = 1;
   frame = insertObjectAnnotation(img,'rectangle',bboxes,D);
   step(videoPlayer,frame);
end
```

Comment: Could you please share your code and what results you see? It is hard to help with no code/results to see.

Comment: Hi there, i cant get vision.people to work together. but for now i am using blob with max and min pixel to detect object smiler to human size. 

obj.blobAnalyser = vision.BlobAnalysis('BoundingBoxOutputPort', true, ...
            'AreaOutputPort', true, 'CentroidOutputPort', true, ...
            'MinimumBlobArea', 800, 'MaximumBlobArea', 2500);

Comment: I was just wondering is it possible to detect people on 'vision.ForegroundDetector' on Gaussians?

Comment: I have edited in the question what i have done so far.

Answer (score 1):

OK. So here's what I think is happening: the resolution of the atrium.mp4 video is not high enough to make reliable detections using `vision.PeopleDetector`. Here's what I did to modify your code:

```
video = VideoReader('atrium.mp4');
peopleDetector = vision.PeopleDetector;
videoPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer;

while hasFrame(video)
   img = readFrame(video);
   img = imresize(img, 3); % resize the frame to make people large enough
   [bboxes,scores] = step(peopleDetector,img);
   D = 1;
   frame = insertObjectAnnotation(img,'rectangle',bboxes,D);
   step(videoPlayer,frame);
end
```

I now see fairly consistent detections in the video, but they are still not tracked all the time, and there seems to be some erroneous detections (one, specifically at the right bottom corner of the video). To avoid these issues, I would do something like what this demo does:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/track-face-raspberry-pi2.html

In essence, this demo uses face detection only when there are no detections, and switches over to tracking once a detection has been made. That way, your processing loop is significantly faster (tracking is less computationally demanding than detection), and you can have (in general) higher fidelity tracking than independent detections in each frame. You could also include some other heuristics such as no movements at all in > 50 frames implies a false positive, and such.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Will research more into it